# mouseover fired for every element in div

Tags: angular

In my Angular 10 app I need to detect the mouse over event when cursor enters a div:

```html
<div (mouseover)="onmouseover($event)">
  <span>element 1</span>
  <span>element 2</span>
  <span>element 3</span>
  <span>element 4</span>
</div>
```

Unfortunately the event is not only fired when the mouse moves over the `div` itself, but also for each of the containing elements separately.

How can I prevent this behavior? The event should only be fired once for the whole div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the expected behavior of the [`mouseover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event) event.

> The `mouseover` event is fired at an Element when a pointing device (such as a mouse or trackpad) is used to move the cursor onto the element or one of its child elements.

Instead you could use the [`mouseenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event) event

> The `mouseenter` event is fired at an Element when a pointing device (usually a mouse) is initially moved

Try the following

```html
<div (mouseenter)="onmouseover($event)">
  <span>element 1</span>
  <span>element 2</span>
  <span>element 3</span>
  <span>element 4</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this example it's same like this

HTML file

```
<div (mouseover)="changeText=true" (mouseout)="changeText=false">
  <span *ngIf="!changeText">Hide</span>
  <span *ngIf="changeText">Show</span>
</div>
```

TS file

```
@Component({
   selector: '---',
   templateUrl: './--.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
    changeText: boolean;
    constructor() {
       this.changeText = false;
    }
}
```